# Variable in subelement python elementtree

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I use elementtree in python. I need to use a variable instead text in the subelement `.text`

**Example:**

```
ET.SubElement(pv,"title", lang="en").text = "ertyuiiuyghgvc"
```

i need

```
ET.SubElement(pv,"title", lang="en").text = myvariable[1]
```

any help?

Comment: whats the matter with your approach? is `myvariable` a list that contains more then 1 element of which the 2nd element (index 1) is a string? whats the error produced? what is your exact questions/problem?

Comment: You might also edit your question and provide a _full_  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can copy & paste your code into our IDE and get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

yes, my variable is also a string, the error is instead the xml file reproduce like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>-<dt>-<city id="paris"><display-name lang="fr">paris</display-name></city>-<it route="paris" stop="20181006000000 +0000" start="20181005230000 +0000"><title lang="fr">ertyuiiuyghgvc</title></it>
```

print only:

ertyuiiuyghgvc

only if i use a variable instead "mytext"

Comment: This does not look like an actual answer. If you want to clarify the question, please edit the question.